# How do I configure Pony/Sinatra to send data from two different forms?

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra

I've a web page with two forms on it.
There is a general contact form and a shopping cart like response section from customers for sale people to respond to with the customer's choices.

I know nothing about Ruby and I'm having trouble assimilating on just how this is supposed to work with the routes pointing to the Sinatra email template. 
Code as follows...

**** Mailer.rb ****

```
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'pony'

    Pony.options = {
      via: :smtp,
      via_options: {
        openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
        address: 'mail.myserver.com',
        port: '587',
        user_name: 'test@myserver.com',
        password: '********',
        authentication: :plain,
        domain: "mail.myserver.com" # the HELO domain provided by the client to the server

      }
    }

class Mailer < Sinatra::Base
  post '/contact' do
    options = {
      from: "test@myserver.com",
      to: 'client@clientaddress.com',
      subject: "Contact Form",
      body: "#{params['name']} <#{params['email']}> \n" + params['message']
    }

    Pony.mail(options)

    redirect '/'
  end

 post '/build-tool' do
    options = {
      from: "test@myserver.com",
      to: 'client@clientaddress.com',
      subject: "Custom Build Form",
      body: "#{params['name']} <#{params['email']}> \n" + params['message']
    }

    Pony.mail(options)

    redirect '/'
  end   

end
```

***** HTML Form One *****

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/contact">
 contact information inputs
</form>
```

***** HTML Form Two *****

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/build-tool">
build tool inputs
</form>
```

***** Config.rb *****

```
map '/contact' do
  run Mailer
end

map '/build-tool' do
  run Mailer
end
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code? Basically, Pony is a mailer class that is used in your sinatra app to send mails after form submition.

Comment: How do I configure Pony/Sinatra to send data from two different forms?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sinatra directly figures out routes, so if you make a POST request to '/contact', it will invoke the code inside the `post '/contact'` definition, so you don't have to do whatever you're doing in `config.rb`.
2. When you `redirect '/'`, it means that the server expects a root route to be defined, which is missing in your class definition.
3. The HTML tags go into a [view](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates) which gets rendered via Sinatra.

These are the three things that require changes. First we define a `/` route which renders the HTML form elements we need:

```
# mailer.rb

require 'sinatra/base' # note the addition of /base here.
require 'pony'

# pony options code same as before

class Mailer < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  # post routes same as before
end
```

HTML gets rendered from a view template. By default, Sinatra will look up views inside the `views/` directory.

```
# views/index.erb

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/contact">
  contact information inputs
  submit button
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/build-tool">
  build tool inputs
  submit button
</form>
```

ERB is a templating languages that's bundled with the Ruby language, so you don't have to install any new gem. There are more [languages listed in the documentation.](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Available%20Template%20Languages)
And the [`config.ru`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Serving%20a%20Modular%20Application) will look like:

```
# config.ru
# Note the file change. This is called a Rackup file. config.rb is
# a more general purpose file used by many libraries, so it's better
# to keep this separate.

require_relative 'mailer.rb'

run Mailer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that each form corresponds to a specific route, sending the form data to that action.  In other words, "form one" sends all input fields it contains in a `POST` request to `/contact` and "form two" sends all its input fields in a `POST`to `/build-tool`.

My suggestion would be to incorporate both forms together into one form and just play with the styling of the page to make it look like two.  That way you will get all input fields submitted to your Sinatra app together and you can send whatever mail best applies to what was input.